# Android wear Watchface fails to install

Tags: android

This is the error im getting from adb:

```
10-27 15:14:44.973      356-381/system_process W/PackageSettings﹕ Skipping PackageSetting{b3d9ed58 andm.simplecarbonfiberwatchface/10023} due to missing metadata
10-27 15:14:45.063      356-381/system_process W/PackageSettings﹕ Skipping PackageSetting{b3d9ed58 andm.simplecarbonfiberwatchface/10023} due to missing metadata
10-27 15:14:46.793      356-381/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ Package andm.simplecarbonfiberwatchface codePath changed from /data/app/andm.simplecarbonfiberwatchface-1.apk to /data/app/andm.simplecarbonfiberwatchface-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
10-27 15:14:46.793      356-381/system_process E/PackageManager﹕ Package andm.simplecarbonfiberwatchface signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!
10-27 15:14:46.803      356-381/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/andm.simplecarbonfiberwatchface-2.apk
10-27 15:14:49.513    1181-1194/com.google.android.clockwork.packageinstaller E/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Package install failed andm.simplecarbonfiberwatchface, returnCode -7
10-27 15:14:51.863      356-381/system_process W/PackageSettings﹕ Skipping PackageSetting{b3d9ed58 andm.simplecarbonfiberwatchface/10023} due to missing metadata
10-27 15:14:56.063      356-381/system_process W/PackageSettings﹕ Skipping PackageSetting{b3d9ed58 andm.simplecarbonfiberwatchface/10023} due to missing metadata
10-27 15:14:56.163      356-381/system_process W/PackageSettings﹕ Skipping PackageSetting{b3d9ed58 andm.simplecarbonfiberwatchface/10023} due to missing metadata
```

Here is my git: https://github.com/theunholy/SimpleCarbonFiberWatchFace/tree/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says: `signatures do not match the previously installed version`

You're trying to install an APK with the same package name of an APK that you've previously installed. This is fine, except that the two APKs were built/signed with different certificates. Your options are:

1. Uninstall the APK you already have, then try to install the new APK
2. Or, find the certificate that was used for the first APK, and sign the new APK with that. Note that every machine will have a different default certificate used for debug builds
3. Or, probably ill-advised - just change the package name of the app.

Comment: Thanks Sam i will look in too this, il report back if it works or not, this is strange ether way, iv always used the same key for all my projects.

Comment: Turns out the wear emulator was keeping part of the apk, inside data/app-bin, so i went ahead and wiped the emulators data, and bam the watchface installs without problems, thanks so much for the help Sam, cant believe i got stuck on this problem for so many days.